# Pandas: Split a string and then create a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Let's say you have Col1.

How do you create the new column 'Col2' after you split the string values in Col1 until you see _?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Edit to handle strings without '_':

```
df['Col2'] = (np.where(df['Col1'].str.contains('_'),
                  df['Col1'].str.split('_').str[1],
                  df['Col1']))
```

OR as COLDSPEED suggests in comments:

```
df['Col1'].str.split('_').str[-1]
```

You can use the .str access with indexing:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].str.split('_').str[1]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['Name_John','Name_Jay','Name_Sherry']})
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].str.split('_').str[1]
```

Output:

```
          Col1    Col2
0    Name_John    John
1     Name_Jay     Jay
2  Name_Sherry  Sherry
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This works very well. Sometimes, the Col1 has values like "Cherry", meaning there is no Name_ in front of Cherry. How do I implement this such that the Col2 will still have Cherry if there's no Name_ in front of it?

Comment: @JunJang `df['Col1'].str.split('_').str[-1]`

Answer (score 14):

You can simply use `str.split()` method with `expand=True` argument.

For example:

```
ncaa[['Win', 'Lose']] = ncaa['Record'].str.split('-', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this will work . `If...else` logic here is for your additional requested, when do not have `'_'` keep the original

```
   df['Col2']= df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1] if x.find('_')!=-1 else x )
```